# display categories with full details

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I need to display the categories on my wordpress which has a parent and have sub categories under it. The main problem is that 'm having trouble displaying all the categories with full details with description and a unique `div` on it for an image.

The ones I'm using right now is this.
Reference for the string args for this method is [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/)

```
<ul>
    <?php wp_list_categories( array(
        'title_li' => __( 'asd' ),
            'hide_title_if_empty' => false,
        'show_option_all' => false,
            'use_desc_for_title' => true,
            'child_of' => 2
    ) ); ?>
</ul>
```

It generates everything I need except that I need to display the description as a text below the title and create a `div` to place an image on it.

```
<ul>
<li class="categories">asd
   <ul>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-10"><a href="http://www.play.com/play/category/good/">good</a>
      </li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-6"><a href="http://www.play.com/play/category/collections/">collections</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

The second option that I have is this one. Basically its a custom way of generatng list of categories but not quite sure if I can able to only display the categories under the child of page id 2 which is the parent category. and also hide the element which is displaying how many post do I have on a category.

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories();
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    if ($cat->category_parent != 0) {
        echo '<span style="padding-left:10px;">';
    }
    echo '<a href="'.get_option('home').get_option('category_base').'/'.$cat->category_nicename.'/">'.$cat->cat_name.'</a> ('.$cat->category_count.')';
    if ($cat->category_description != '') {
        echo ' - '.$cat->category_description;
    }
    if ($cat->category_parent != 0) {
        echo '</span>';
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
?>
```

What I did is use the 2nd option but I'm having problems displaying a specific category id. Code below display all categories though I only need to display categories under specific parent. which is cat id 2.

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories();
    echo '<ul>';
foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    if ($cat->category_parent != 0) {
        echo '<li>';
    }
    echo '<a href="'.get_option('home').get_option('category_base').'/'.$cat->category_nicename.'/">'.$cat->cat_name.'</a>';
    if ($cat->category_description != '') {
        echo '<p>'.$cat->category_description.'</p>';
    }
    if ($cat->category_parent != 0) {
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Corrected some looping and optimize abit

```
<?php
    $categories = get_categories();
    echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
            if ($cat->category_parent != 0) {
                echo '<li>';
                echo '<a href="'.get_option('home').get_option('category_base').'/'.$cat->category_nicename.'/">'.$cat->cat_name.'</a>';
                    if ($cat->category_description != '') {
                        echo '<p>'.$cat->category_description.'</p>';
                    }
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: I think you should put categories into a key => value array, where key is a category ID. That way you can easily access each category with O(1) access time, so you can find specific category without looping through all of them.

Comment: see latest code. i only need to get the category of a specific parent. the one right now is getting every child category. I not quite sure on how will I target the one I want.

Comment: To find a specific category under specific parent, you can use 2 dimensional array: array["specificParent"]["specificCategory"]. its still O(1).

Comment: I think, to make it easier, you should create a class Category, and then append each category as value of specific parent. e.g. array["parent100"][categoryObject1]; array["parent100"][categoryObject2]; etc.

Comment: Ah, you got a class already. so it should be easy